# VBA Excel - Copy Rows to Another Workbook Sheet with conditions

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements

Newbie trying to mix and match codes on an excel workbook that is configured to prompt a login and to allow diff Id and PW to see different sheets.

```
If Me.userid.Value = "admin" And Me.userpw.Value = "admin" Then
MsgBox "Login Successful!", vbInformation, "Login Alert"
MsgBox "Entry and use data with caution and exercise confidentiality at all times!", vbExclamation, "Critical Reminder"

Unload Me

Sheets("Summary Report View").Visible = True
Sheets("Summary Report View").Select
Sheets("Data Validation").Visible = True
Sheets("Data Entry 1").Visible = True
Sheets("Data Entry 2").Visible = True
Sheets("Data Entry 3").Visible = True
```

I have this challenge not being able to copy data from other workbook (a particular worksheet called 6-9months) to this workbook that I'm working on into Data Entry 1. The condition is to pick up all rows with the name "John" in Column I and paste to my active workbook sheet named "data entry 1". I attempted to activate the codes through a button click to pick up all the rows but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Confirmation = MsgBox("Are you sure to removal all contents? This is not reversible", vbYesNo, "Confirmation")

    Select Case Confirmation
    Case Is = vbYes

    Sheets("Data Entry 2").Cells.ClearContents
    MsgBox "Information removed", vbInformation, "Information"

    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$
    Dim myValue As String
    Dim P As Integer, Q As Integer
    Txt = "John"

    MyPath = "C:\Users\gary.tham\Desktop\"
    MyWB = "Book1.xlsx"

    'MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow

    If Cells(i, 11) = txt Then
    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    P = Worksheets.Count
    For Q = 1 To P
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Q).Name = "Data Entry 2" Then
    Worksheets("Data Entry 2").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Q).Paste
    End If
    Next Q
    End If
    Next i

    Case Is = vbNo
    MsgBox "No Changes Made", vbInformation, "Information"

    End Select
```

Comment: @Ralph, thanks much for the note and I appreciate it. Do understand that this is not a code-writing service as it's more of a community which helps each other on code errors. I've update the codes being used ("which I run through a series of websites and youtube")... Apologies for the troubles as Im not too familiar with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential problem with your code is that you are working with multiple Excel files at the same time (1) the file you are opening and searching for "John" and the (2) current file from which the macro is being called and to which we are importing the data. Yet, your code does not reference the two files but merely states to search for "john" in the `ActiveSheet`. Furthermore, you are not telling VBA in which of the two files you want to search the currently active sheet.

So, if you are working with multiple files then you should specifically address everything and don't ask VBA to make assumptions which file or which sheet or which cell on which sheet in which file you mean. Confused? If VBA would be a person then he/she would probably also be confused. Yet, VBA just makes assumptions and you are left to wonder why the code doesn't do what you expect it to do. Hence, when working with multiple files you should use the following explicit (!) references and tell VBA exactly what you want:

`Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value2`

or

`Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value2`

Having said that, I changed your code to make use of the above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDataFromAnotherFileIfSearchTextIsFound()

Dim strPath As String
Dim wbkImportFile As Workbook
Dim shtThisSheet As Worksheet
Dim shtImportSheet As Worksheet

Dim lngrow As Long
Dim strSearchString As String
Dim strImportFile As String

'uPPer or lOwEr cases do not matter (as it is currently setup)
strSearchString = "jOHn"
strImportFile = "Book1.xlsx"

Set shtThisSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry 2")
'If the import file is in the same folder as the current file
'   then you could also use the following instead
'strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
strPath = "C:\tmp" '"C:Users\gary.tham\Desktop"

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wbkImportFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & "\" & strImportFile)
'To speed up things you could also (if acceptable) open the file
'   read-only without updating links to other Excel files (if there are any):
'Set wbkImportFile = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & "\" & strImportFile, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False)
Set shtImportSheet = wbkImportFile.Worksheets("6-9months")

shtThisSheet.Cells.ClearContents
For lngrow = 2 To shtImportSheet.Cells(shtImportSheet.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(1, shtImportSheet.Cells(lngrow, "I").Value2, strSearchString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        shtImportSheet.Range(shtImportSheet.Cells(lngrow, 1), shtImportSheet.Cells(lngrow, 13)).Copy
        shtThisSheet.Range("A" & shtThisSheet.Cells(shtThisSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
    End If
Next lngrow

wbkImportFile.Close SaveChanges:=False

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Note, that the above code is not an exact copy of yours. There are two changes:

(1) The sheet "Data Entry 2" in the current file (the file you are importing to) will be cleared without asking the user.

(2) The sheet "Data Entry 2" is directly referenced without the above check: if there actually is a sheet by that name in the current file.

So, don't forget to make the proper adjustments to suit your needs.

Do let me know if this solution works for you or if you have any more questions.

Comment: the codes worked perfectly good and I've modified it to fit in more requirements! Thank you!!

Do I need to put in the working code to update the question so that it shows the working codes?

Comment: No, everything is fine as it is. You had a question and there is an answer to it (which you accepted as an applicable solution). The question shows the problem you were having and the answer shows the solution to your problem. Like this, the post can possibly help someone else in the future with their problems. So, all is good. But thanks for asking. Don't hesitate to come back if you need help again and feel free to read questions from other users. Maybe you can help them with their problems?

Comment: I will be visit this site more regularly. Like you say, perhaps I could be some help to others. Thanks again @ralph