# Copying data from external worksheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to do this thing for a while but I was not able to. I usually would search more etc but I am not very familiar with VBA (only C++ and Java).

I have a Excel file (workbook) with multiple of sheets that all contain data (Source). I have another Excel file that contains again multiple worksheets that contain ONLY the headings (Target).

What I want to do is a code that goes to the target workbook and takes the heading, then goes to the source workbook and loops through all the worksheets until it finds this heading and then copies the data into the target workbook.

Keep in mind all headings in the source file are at the same row in all the worksheets.

[image]

Comment: You won't get exact code for your need. But there are alot of great examples that will help. What you should do is break your problem into smaller ones e.g how to loop over worksheet, how to get worksheet name , etc etc... and try to work and build what you need. If you run into any error SO is always there :-)

Comment: I am currently reading but its hard to start so deep without a proper base but thanks for the advice.

Comment: This is actually a pretty common thing. You should be able to easily find code for this.

Comment: I just answered (yesterday) a question which was somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36912162/vba-excel-copy-rows-to-another-workbook-sheet-with-conditions/36939973#36939973 I hope this helps.

Comment: Its hard to explain a block of code without knowing the basics.. I think I give up ill just do it manually :(..wasting too much time

Answer (score 1):

This code should solve your problem;

```
Sub Read_External_Workbook()

    '''''Define Object for Target Workbook
    Dim Target_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Source_Workbook As Workbook
    Dim Target_Path As String

    '''''Assign the Workbook File Name along with its Path
    '''''Change path of the Target File name
    Target_Path = "D:\Sample.xlsx"
    Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks.Open(Target_Path)
    Set Source_Workbook = ThisWorkbook

    '''''With Target_Workbook object now, it is possible to pull any data from it
    '''''Read Data from Target File - Assuming that your headers's locations are absolute.
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = Target_Data

    '''''Update Target File - 
    Source_data = Source_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 1)
    Target_Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = Source_data

    '''''Close Target Workbook
    Source_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Save
    Target_Workbook.Close False

    '''''Process Completed
    MsgBox "Task Completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: My data doesnt have to be in same order? I want the code to loop through the source_workbook.. for example the first column I may need could be in the first worksheet while the second column could be in the third worksheet?